# How to prove this matrix identity?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This was a single step in a derivation, so I'm assuming there is a way to "see" this without writing down the expression for each entry:
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left(x_i-\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i \right) \left(x_i-\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i \right)^T = XHX^T$$
where
$$X = [x_1 x_2 \cdots x_n] \quad H=I-n^{-1}\mathbb{1}_{n \times n}$$
where $\mathbb{1}_{n \times n}$ is the $n \times n$ matrix of ones.

Comment: I am a little confused by your notation.  Ordinarily matrix entries have ij suffices, but I see only i's in your left hand side.  And can you confirm that $1_{nxn}$ has a 1 in every position?

Comment: $x_i$'s are vectors. If it helps, you could refer to http://www.gatsby.ucl.ac.uk/~gretton/coursefiles/lecture4_introToRKHS.pdf (page 18), where this identity appears.

Comment: The assumption is totally unwarranted, by the way: a single  step may well be something that the author does not wish to write out in detail, but will take the reader half an hour to get through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to use different indices in different sums. Expand
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left(x_i-\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{j=1}^n x_j \right) \left(x_i-\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_k \right)^T $$
as 
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n  x_i x_i^T -\frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n x_i x_k^T -\frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n x_j x_i^T +\frac{1}{n^2} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \sum\limits_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n x_j x_k^T  $$
and then get rid of extraneous indices:
 $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n  x_i x_i^T -\frac{2}{n} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n x_i x_k^T   +\frac{n}{n^2}   \sum\limits_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n x_j x_k^T  $$
This further simplifies to 
 $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n  x_i x_i^T -\frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n x_i x_k^T    $$
  where $I-n^{-1}1_{n\times n}$ is clearly seen.